# Unable to test self-hosted bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I have developed a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework in C#, and am in the process of trying to deploy it to a web server instead of Azure. The web server runs Windows Server 2012 R2, and has IIS 8.5 installed. The bot works fine locally, and can be tested there using the emulator without any problems.

I have configured a site in IIS on the web server for the bot and deployed the bot code there, as well as configured the app ID and password. When using the "test connection" facility on the Bot Framework site, I am given an "endpoint authorisation succeeded" message. However when attempting to test it using the emulator (or the chat facility built in to the portal site) I do not receive any replies, and in the emulator all responses are shown as internal server errors.

I have ngrok running in the background to forward the connections to my development machine, and have updated the emulator URL field to contain the URL indicated in ngrok's "forwarding" section. However the list of HTTP requests in ngrok's console window does not populate when I am trying to conduct a chat.

I have tried to use [this previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462841/4829250) to get more details about whatever internal server error may be occurring, but after deploying this code I receive a stack trace. Again, this works fine locally and can be tested with the emulator without any issues.

Can anybody advise on where I may be going wrong, or share their experiences with debugging these kinds of errors? Bot Framework does not seem to provide a terribly good debugging experience unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem was resolved by upgrading the server to run the latest available version of the .NET Framework (4.6.2). 4.5 was installed, and this is not compatible with Bot Framework.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the endpoint URL in the emulator to the actual bot endpoint (same URL you provided in the dev portal). The emulator is able send messages directly to your bot. The ngrok URL is for tunneling replies from your bot back to the emulator.

Comment: Hi Eric, the "Bot URL" field in the emulator already matches the endpoint URL that I've configured in the portal.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your statement "...updated the emulator URL field to contain the URL indicated in ngrok's "forwarding" section". It would be incorrect to put the ngrok URL as the emulator's bot endpoint.

Comment: Let me back up and check my understanding. Are you running ngrok on the IIS machine to forward messages to your bot? If so, then an ngrok bot endpoint is valid. Second, are you running ngrok on your dev machine (to forward messages to the emulator)? Third question, are you using the new Bot Framework emulator (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator)?

Comment: If you are using ngrok, the url in the dev portal should be the one provided by ngrok. If you are using the newer emulator, and using ngrok from there, make sure that the localhost url being routed reaches to your IIS. Usually at http://localhost:4040/status you will see the ngrok status

Comment: @EricAnderson I had an older version of the emulator installed, which will be where the confusion is coming from. I've downloaded the latest version from the link you provided, configured it with the path to ngrok and set the bot endpoint, ID and password, but have the same issue of all messages being met with a 500 error. ngrok is only running on my development machine to forward messages from the bot to the emulator - it is not set up on the server.

Comment: @weeroid, so the IIS thing is not relevant to the issue you are having then, right? Basically you are trying to use ngrok to,for example, test your bot in some of the out of the box channels like skype. If my understanding is correct, could you please update the question?Also, can you go to http://localhost:4040/status with the emulator opened and see what URL ngrok is routing to

Comment: @EzequielJadib I mentioned IIS because I'm unsure which information is relevant, and which isn't - the bulk of the documentation appears to concentrate on deploying to Azure. I am unable to find much documentation on how to set up or troubleshoot a self-hosted bot. I felt that including the maximum amount of information in my question about what I'm trying to achieve would be the best approach.

The ngrok instance on my development machine is routing to port 23233 of localhost. I also just tried adding the bot as a Skype contact, but I did not receive any replies to my messages there either.

Comment: @weedroid Are you able to get additional information about the 500 (such has callstack or error message) from your IIS logs?

Comment: And you have your local bot running in localhost:23233? because if it's not running there then it won't work. But it's not clear to me if you want to use the bot hosted on IIS or a local bot running in visual studio?

Comment: @EricAnderson I set up failed request tracking on the server I'm trying to host the bot on, and got a stack trace which indicated that the issue may be due to only having .NET Framework 4.5.2 installed on the server. I'm going to upgrade it and check if this resolves the issue first.